# Вторая из созданных функций не может быть использована SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Мною была создана функция. Это была первая функция в бд, и я ее спокойно вызываю.
Однако когда я создаю вторую функцию, пусть даже точно такую же, но с другим названием, она создается, но если я ее хочу вызвать, вылезает вот такая ошибка.
То есть любую функцию, кроме первой созданной, по сути не возможно нигде вызвать.
С чем такое может быть связано?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка говорит вам, о том что функция не существует. Покажите скрипт создания функции.

Comment: Укажите в скрипте создания явно схему `dbo`, и убедитесь что вызываете функцию работая именно с этой базой.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос. Суть в том,  что это создание функции точно запускал, оно позволяет делать операцию ALTER,  и при попытке пересоздать говорит что такая функция уже есть. dbo. добавил, ни на что не повлияло,  работаю точно в той базе.

Comment: Из другого запроса к функции обратиться можете? `SELECT dbo.KeysNumbers1('asdf');`

Comment: Нет, к функциям кроме первой не получается обратиться ни откуда, даже не возникает такой подсказки после написания "dbo." То есть никакую функцию кроме первой созданной не вызвать даже обычным selectom.

Comment: Судя по скриншоту ошибки, вы только что создали функцию в БД и IntelliSense в SSMS просто пока о ней не знает. Запрос то пробовали запустить? Какая ошибка при выполнении запроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратить внимание нужно на вторую часть сообщения об ошибке. Функций у вас две, смотрите на их схему. Одна будет dbo.KeysNumber1, вторая - с иным префиксом. 
Например: mkruglov239.KeysNumber1
Указывать нужно в явном виде, этот механизм как раз сделан для того, чтобы можно было иметь несколько функций и процедур с одинаковым названием или даже вызывать обе этих функции в одном запросе.

Answer (score 0):

В справке по MS SQL сказано, что предложение `CREATE FUNCTION` может идти только первым в запросе. Создать две функции одним запросом нельзя.

Либо разбивайте на отдельные скрипты, либо, если используете MS SQL Managament Studio, разбивайте скрипт ключевым словом [`GO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188037.aspx)